# Adding animations on Conditional Rendered Component

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

How should I add simple animations like (fade in transition etc...) so when I click on the img, the content just don't pop up on screen on Conditional Rendered Component. I would really appreciate any help. Kind Regards

````
```App Component```
const App =()=>{
const[isMenuOpen, setIsMenuOpen]=React.useState(false)
 const menu = useRef(null)
 const handleMenu = (e) => {
      if (menu.current && !menu.current.contains(e.target)) {
       closeMenu() 
      }
    };
  
  useEffect(() => {
      document.addEventListener('click', handleMenu);
      return () => {
        document.removeEventListener('click', handleMenu);
      };
    }, []);

  return (
        <div className='taskbar'>
           <div ref={menu}>
            <img  className='taskbar__iconsRight' onClick={() => setIsMenuOpen(!isMenuOpen)} 
              src="./images/icons/win7.png"/>
               {isMenuOpen ? <Menu />: null}
           </div>
        </div>
      )
     }

export default App

```Menu Component```
import React from 'react'
import {menuIcons} from "../../data"
const Menu = () => {
    return (
        <div className='menu'>
             {menuIcons.map((icon)=>{
                const {id,url,name, img} = icon;
                return (
                <div className='menu__cont'>
                 <span className='menu__icon' key={id}>
                    <div className='menu__info'>
                     <a className='menu__link'target="_blank" rel="noreferrer noopener" href={url}>                  
                       <img className='menu__image' src={img}/>                                                        
                       <h4 className='menu__text'>{name}</h4>                   
                     </a>
                    </div>                 
                 </span>     
                </div>
                )                     
              })}                  
        </div>
    )
}
export default Menu
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add css animation to your Menu component, which will be triggered on initial render. Wrap your component with className "animation" and add css like so:

```
.animation{
  animation: fade-in 0.3s ease-in forwards;
  opacity: 0;
}

@keyframes fade-in {
  from {
    opactiy: 0;
  } to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

If you would like to add fade-out animation I would highly recommend react-spring library, which make it very simple https://www.react-spring.io/.